# How to update a table copy in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, synchronize

I have two identical databases - one for development (DEV) and one for production (PROD) (both SQL Server 2008).

I have updated the contents of a certain table in DEV and now I want to sync the corresponding table in PROD.

I have not changed the table schema, only some the data inside the table (I have both changed existing rows and added some new rows).

How can I easily transfer the changes in DEV to the corresponding table in PROD?

Note, that the values in the automatic identity column mgiht not match exactly between the two tables. However, I know that I have only made changes to rows having the same value in another column.

- Martin

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613983/sql-server-synchronizing-2-tables-on-2-different-databases

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the replication, you can Create update, Insert and delete trigger in DEV database and update PROD by trigger.
or you can create view of DEV database table on the PROD database.