# Keep Tables synchonized

Tags: sql-server

I've two database tables in different databases.

Every insert, update or delete at one of the tables should effect the same on the other side.

Goal should be to keep both Tables synchronized.

Should this be done by Trigger, Replication or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server - synchronizing 2 tables on 2 different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613983/sql-server-synchronizing-2-tables-on-2-different-databases)

Comment: replication is a good feature to sync database/tables